# Illustrator artboard and image size

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need an image that will be printed with the proportions 160x230cm.
I have made my artboard size 160x230cm(I am starting to think this wasn't a good idea because it is too big and everything is really slow).
To what size do I resize the artboard and how can I export the image so it won't lose quality when printing 160x230cm? How big does it have to be? What ppi do I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I export the image so it won't lose quality when printing?

I would personally suggest Saving as a .pdf. This option will allow you to choose [High Quality Print] from the 'Presets' and you can also go to 'Marks and Bleeds' and add any if they are necessary.

> How big does it have to be?

If you want your image to print out 160x230cm, as far as I'm aware, your artboard will need to be 160x230cm.

> What ppi do I use?

300dpi/ppi is standard for printing.

Comment: this answer contains incorrect information. An artboard doesn't need to be 1:1 scale to print, specially if it's a vector file. For more info, always ask your printer, they'll know better what specs will print better in their equipment.